# Trace and cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, trace, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ be the cyclotomic field of $p$th roots of unity for the prime $p$ and let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$. Let $\zeta$ denote any $p$th root of unity. Please show that $\sum_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(\zeta)$ is $-1$ or $p-1$ depending on whether $\zeta$ is or is not a primitive $p$th root of unity.

Comment: If $\zeta$ is not primitive then it has to be 1 since $p$ is prime. So we get $\phi(p)=p-1$ in this case. If $\zeta$ is primitive then $\sigma_k(\zeta)=\zeta^k$ where $\sigma_k\in G$.So $\zeta+...+\zeta^{p-1}=-1$.

Comment: So...why did you ask the question if you know the answer, @user70520 ?

Comment: I was looking for another way of doing it.

Comment: Why is trace $p-1$ and not just 1 for the non primitive case? Isn't $x-1$ the minimal polynomial over the rationals?